# async await puppeteer.launch not working onClick with puppeteer-web

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, .net, puppeteer

I'm trying to be able to run a puppeteer node task on the server when a button is clicked in the browser. I'm not sure if I have the correct environment set up because I get `"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined".`

When I run $node src/js/pdfTest.js from CMD, it outputs the file as expected so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm using puppeteer/puppeteer-web.js, C# .NET, JavaScript, with Node 10.15.0 installed on my local windows/WSL machine

pdf.html

```
<head>
    <script src="src/js/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/libs/handlebars/handlebars-v4.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/handlebarsHelpers.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/templates.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="pdfBtn">Save PDF</button>
    <div id="pdf">
    </div>
    <script src="src/js/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/pdfTest.js"></script>
</body>
```

(I load a handlebars template on the page inside the #pdf div from another js file)

pdf.js

```
var Pdf = (function () {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        render();
    });

    function render() {
    console.log("rendering pdf.js");
        $("#pdfBtn").on("click", function () {
            PdfTest.printPDF();
        });
    }

    return {
        render: render
    }
}());
```

pdfTest.js

```
var PdfTest = (function () {
    async function printPDF() {
        const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

        (async () => {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();

            await page.goto('http://localhost:60639/pdf.html');
            await page.waitFor(2000);
            await page.pdf({ path: 'src/pdf/mynewpdf.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true })
            await browser.close();
        })()
    };

    return {
       printPDF: printPDF
    }
}());
```

This code from pdfTest.js (if I replace the above with just this snippet) is working perfectly when I call it from the command line.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://localhost:60639/pdf.html');
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.pdf({ path: 'src/pdf/mynewpdf.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true })
    await browser.close();
})()
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at puppeteer-web.js:8902
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promisified (puppeteer-web.js:8894)
    at Launcher.launch (puppeteer-web.js:5074)
    at module.exports.launch (puppeteer-web.js:7887)
    at pdfTest.js:85
    at Object.printPDF (pdfTest.js:92)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (postTrekPdf.js:43)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In browser javascript there is no function `require()`

You have to send Event to main thread becouse this code works on client side in browser and browser can't open another browser. You can also send API request to eg. localhost/dosmthn.

Make webserver on console that sends html file. In this file when you click button API request is send and your nodejs application do puppeteer things. And return to you (browser) pdf file. Then you can display this file in browser.

I hope it helps